# Graphics card not working

Tags: graphics-card, motherboard

I went to turn on my PC today and it wouldn’t turn on. It makes five short beeps and doesn’t start. I’ve taken all of the parts out to clean them and put them back in again but there’s been no luck. I

In my manual, 5 beeps indicate a CPU problem but when I take the graphics card out and use a [SCART](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SCART) lead, the computer works perfectly, so it can't be a CPU problem. Could this be a motherboard or graphics card issue? The graphics card's fan still works when plugged in though. Any advice would be appreciated. Thanks.

Graphics card : MSI GEFORCE GTX 1050
Motherboard: [Gigabyte B250M DS3H](http://download.gigabyte.us/FileList/Manual/mb_manual_ga-b250m-ds3h_e.pdf)

Comment: Search for "five beeps" and your motherboard (or at least vendor). The graphics card won't beep, this is the motherboard complaining.

Comment: What is the SCART lead attached to on each end? Hint: If your video card is dragging down the power supply output, when you run without it using Intel(R) HD Graphics support, that might provide a clew. HD Graphics, depending on which CPU you have, might run A)1 x D-Sub port, supporting a maximum resolution of 1920x1200@60 Hz B) 1 x DVI-D port, supporting a maximum resolution of 1920x1200@60 Hz * The DVI-D port does not support D-Sub connection by adapter. and/or C) 1 x HDMI 1.4 port, supporting a maximum resolution of 4096x2160@24 Hz

Comment: I have formatted the PC and updated BIOS to the latest version but it still isn't working. When I connect the graphics card to the PC and I turn it on, the motherboard beeps 5 times. While the graphics cards is installed, I've tried to connect the HDMI cable to the Graphics card but it doesn't work and it doesn't work when I connect the HDMI and the VGA to the motherboard either. However, with graphics card out, the VGA and the HDMI work.
This graphics card does not need power from the power supply.

Thanks a lot. I appreciate it.

Comment: Hi. I've managed to turn on the PC with the GPU connected through an HDMI cable connected to the motherboard. On the Device Manager, the graphics card name appears but with a yellow warning sign next to it, and the error 43 appears. So I don't think it is the motherboard slot or the graphics card themselves, as the GPU is detected by the PC and the fan works. I've reinstalled different official drivers for the GPU but it still has the error 43. Thanks a lot.